Numbers, or are they?
22-21-15-3-19-23-14-6-7-26-1-18 12-1-18 17-26-26-24-12 14-26-14-22-7-7-5-7-17 22-12-14-1-10-26-7-12-14-26-18 2-14-6-17-22-14 22-10-17-10-22-26 12-10-7

Can you figure the meaning of this?

Hint:

 Sizzling.
 Is that lava?
 A battle ensues.


I have the high ground.

Don't underestimate my puz-zle:)

The answer is

 Anakin Skywalker: I have brought peace, freedom, justice, and security to my new Empire.
Obi-Wan Kenobi: Your new Empire?
Anakin Skywalker: Don't make me kill you.
Obi-Wan Kenobi: Anakin, my allegiance is to the Republic, to democracy!
Anakin Skywalker: If you're not with me, then you're my enemy.
Obi-Wan Kenobi: Only a Sith deals in absolutes. I will do what I must
Anakin Skywalker: You will try.

because

 convert with A1Z26, Rot13 it, you get ihbpfjastmne yne dmmky amaittrtd iyanwmtyame oasdia iwdwim ywt, which are the initial letters of this memeable dialog in Star Wars Episode 3.


Do you know Stsr Wars that well to have guessed it just by first letters?

@webadventurer The hint in the OP made me pretty sure this is about SW Episode 3, because of the iconic battle scene. I was somewhat active on r/PrequelMemes a few years ago, which burned some quotes into my head and helped me figure it out.

Then the puzzle should have cinema tag attached to it for a further help....

I don't think puzzles with enigmatic-puzzle as a tag should include other tags which relate to the final answer, as that will sort of give away part of the solving, no?

Now that I think of it, I should have used multiple ROTSwink

@M.Riyan does puzzling even have a cinema tag? The knowledge tag is fine, it covers all knowledge that isn't strictly related to puzzles

@NoName, the movies tag I meant
